# How to create a stretchy header in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm looking for ways to create a stretchy header in Kotlin, for now I came across multiple solutions for Swift.

[image]

Comment: Adding the 'react-native' or 'reactjs' tag will mean more people who can help you are likely to see this !

Comment: @Tenfour04 I appreciate they are not directly linked to Kotlin, but Kotlin is a derivative of the java programming lanugage, perhaps someone who has programmed using react-native or reactjs could help. Was just a suggestion

Comment: @Limun, don't tag React unless you're using React instead of Kotlin. These are two mutually exclusive ways of building a layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using this [library](https://github.com/valkriaine/Bouncy) for the bouncy effect, close enough!